# UWP ListView Content Margin

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a `ListView` which has a `Header`. How do I set the margins of those `ListViewItem`s only not including the `Header`?

For example, the `ListView` with `Header` looks like this:

[image]

I want the `ListViewItem` to be like the image below:

[image]

The second `ListView` doesn't have a `Header`, so I was able to directly set its margin.

Now with the header, how can set the margin of the space wrapping around the `ListViewItems` only?

Comment: Hi, please post your code for a better understanding. I don't quite understand which part of the Header you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ListView` has a header, you can add margin between the header and the items by setting a `Padding` to the root layout control within the header. For example, your header could look like this:

```
<ListView.HeaderTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Padding="0,0,0,12">
         ...
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.HeaderTemplate>
```

Setting `Margin` of this layout control should however work equally as well.